# Mosquitto bridge not receiving messages when sending a lot of msgs

Tags: networking, mqtt, mosquitto, bridge

My local MQTT broker (Mosquitto) will not receive message from the remote one once I am sending a lot of msgs (ros laserscans and costmaps). It is important for the messages to be received from the remote broker, it is OK to lose or delay msgs send to the remote broker.

Protocol: mqttv5

I can receive msgs with no problem from the remote until i begin sending data.

Is there a setting a can change to help with my problem

My config:

```
connection remote-broker
address {address:port}
topic data/# out 0 "" remoter/namespace/
topic data/debug_control in 1 "" remoter/namespace/
cleansession false
notifications false
remote_clientid Testing
remote_password {username}
remote_username {password}
start_type automatic
try_private true
bridge_cafile {user_cafile}
bridge_insecure false
bridge_certfile {user_certfile}
bridge_keyfile {user_keyfile}
bridge_protocol_version mqttv50
```

I have tried both QOS 0,1 and 2. to no help

I have tried settings `max_inflight_bytes` and `max_queued_bytes` but this didn't seem to help, set to around 2megabytes

Comment: What is the remote broker? Another MQTT instance? If so what happens if you slow the message publishing down, e.g. just send a few messages not huge floods of data?

Comment: Also if it is mosquitto on the other end we need to see that config file as well

Comment: I don't have access to configure or see the configuration of the remote broker,
i don't know the MQTT broker the remote is using

Comment: You have to understand that mosquitto is a single threaded event loop, if you flood it with messages it's going to starve out other actions.

Comment: is there a way I can tell it to prioritise msgs coming from the remote broker compared to other sources or prioritise a specific topic

Comment: No. How are you testing this? is it all with a single client that is also publishing the lidar data? if you attach a separate client does it receive the control messages?

Comment: I am using MQTT explore to connect to both the remote broker as well as the local one, and I am looking if I can see the control message in both the program sending the lidar data as well as in MQTT explore, if i send the control msgs to the local broker it seems to work